# Do I need to back up my swap partition?

Tags: backup, swap, disk-image, clonezilla

I am I wondering why I am not able to see the swap area of Ubuntu in clonezilla. I want to create an image of my Ubuntu. However, I cannot find the swap partition of Ubuntu to image it.

Thanks.

Comment: Frankly, you don't even need to image it  since it contains ZERO data. It can be created after restoring or backing up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ## The swap partition is not needed.

The swap partition is not needed for cloning. To find out why, let's find out what swap does. If you have programs running, and not enough RAM, they are put in swap. At every boot, and through normal operation, data in swap gets cleared time to time, comes and goes, not being needed for data (similar to RAM). Keeping SWAP is like taking a snapshot of RAM, which is only useful for debugging. You only need to backup any non-swap partitions related to Ubuntu. If you need to restore, you can make a new swap partition, just like the one you had before, without risking important data.

Comment: Okay you are definitely right. However, here is a problem. I installed my ubuntu with a swap partition. Then I want to restore my ubuntu using another flash disk. Because my new flash disk has free space, I need to create partitions including swap and ext4 but the question I wonder is that if it is appropriate to create a swap space having different UUID and space amount. In /etc/fstab, UUIDs of the partition is saved. Whenever I create a new swap partition, these UUIDs will not macth. Can it cause a problem in my ubuntu? I hope I was clear enough to explain my concern :)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/171216/527764) is right. Just one amendment; if one wants to clone a complete disk with a swap partition clonezilla doesn't clone the swap partition but creates a swap partition. If one restores the disk the swap partition is created but empty.

Comment: Does Clonezilla act the same way in the case of a swapfile, rather than a swap partition?

Comment: No, a swapfile is stored on a "normal" partition and is cloned by clonefilla.